# Use <p:outputText /> inside <p:imageSwitch />

Tags: jsf, text, primefaces, imageswitcher

I'm trying to display the dynamic values in slideshow using `<p:imageSwitch>`.
But how can use outputText values inside `<p:imageSwitch>`?
this is my code:

```
<p:commandButton onclick="switcher.previous();"/>
<p:imageSwitch effect="fade" widgetVar="switcher" slideshowAuto="false">
    <h:outputText  value="#{msgs.launch}" />
    <h:outputText  value="#{msgs.launch1}" />
    <h:outputText  value="#{msgs.launch2}" />
</p:imageSwitch>
<p:commandButton onclick="switcher.next();"/>
```

Comment: Show your <p:imageSwitch> code.

Comment: <p:imageSwitch  widgetVar="switcher"   slideshowAuto="true">
 <h:outputText  value="#{msgs.launch}" />
  more lines.....
</p:imageSwitch> >

Comment: <p:commandButton onclick="switcher.previous();"/> 
 <p:imageSwitch > 
outputtext values
<p:imageSwitch>                                                                                        <p:commandButton onclick="switcher.next();"/>

Comment: & what are the more lines by the way? I asked you update your question with complete code.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to show text over image?

Comment: i have different dynamic values & in a first slide i need to display one value, then if i click next arrow 2nd value will be visible like that all other values want show in slideshow

Comment: dynamic values for outputText or graphicImage?

Comment: this is my code: <p:commandButton onclick="switcher.previous();"/> 
        <p:imageSwitch effect="fade" widgetVar="switcher" slideshowAuto="false">
              <h:outputText  value="#{msgs.launch}" />
              <h:outputText  value="#{msgs.launch1}" />
              <h:outputText  value="#{msgs.launch2}" />
    </p:imageSwitch> 
    <p:commandButton onclick="switcher.next();"/>

Comment: Try not to post your code in commit. Its a bad approach.

Comment: I want display dynamic values in each slide

Comment: Put your dynamic values in a list and iterate it using ui:repeat, as it is supported by p:imageSwitch.

Comment: if am getting each dynamic values from different bean means what should i do?

Comment: You can wrap your dynamic values into a list in initialization of your current bean.